# Why do we need execution permission although we can run any script without it using "bash script file"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I am wondering when and why do we need execution permission in linux although we can run any script without execute permission when we execute that script using the syntax bellow?

```
bash SomeScriptFile
```

Comment: Duplicative of [Unix execute permission can be easily bypassed. Is it superfluous, or what's the intention behind it?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66550/unix-execute-permission-can-be-easily-bypassed-is-it-superfluous-or-whats-the)

Comment: ...that said, the place where the `+x` bit has strong meaning for security is actually *directories*, not files. On files, it's a performance and usability enhancement -- which is value enough, in and of itself. On a directory, `+x` without `+r` gives the ability to traverse a directory without being able to read its contents -- a very valuable distinction.

Comment: Adding to the discussion: Removing the x-bit from the permission alone does NOT mean that it becomes impossible to execute the program (even if it is a compiled program), and this is also not the purpose of the x-bit. For example, even if I have a compiled program with permission 0444, I can easily run it by copying to my own directory first, set the x-permission in my copy, and then execute the program.

Answer (score 3):

Executing the script by invoking it directly and running the script through `bash` are two very different things.

When you run `bash ~/bin/SomeScriptFile` you are really just executing `bash` -- a command interpreter.  `bash` in turns load the scripts and runs it.

When you run `~/bin/SomeSCriptFile` directly, the system is able to tell this file is a script file and finds the interpreter to run it. There is a big of magic invoking the `#!` on the first line to look for the right interpreter.

The reason we run scripts directly is that the user (and system) couldn't know or care of the command we are running is a script or a compiled executable.

For instance, if I write a nifty shell script called `fixAllIlls` and later I decide to re-write it in `C`, as long a I keep the same interface, the users don't have to do anything different.

To them, it is just a program to run.

*edit*

The operating system checks permissions first for several reasons:

- Checking permissions is faster
- In the days of old, you could have SUID scripts, so one needed to check the permission bits.
- As a result, it was possible to run scripts that you could not actually read the contents of.  (That is still true of binaries.)

Comment: I'm not sure this addresses why there's value for an operating system to be designed to check for `+x` permissions before looking up the relevant magic, finding an interpreter, &c. to execute a command. (I definitely agree that there *is* value, but am not sure this answer addresses the reasoning).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Added some history

Answer (score 2):

Not all programs are scripts — `bash` for example isn't.  So you need execute permission for executable programs.

Also, when you say `bash SomeScriptFile`, the script has to be in the current directory.  If you have the script executable and in a directory on your PATH (e.g. `$HOME/bin`), then you can run the script without the unnecessary circumlocution of `bash $HOME/bin/SomeScriptFile` (or `bash ~/bin/SomeScriptFile`); you can simply run `SomeScriptFile`.  This economy is worth having.

Execute permission on a directory is somewhat different, of course, but also important.  It permits the 'class of user' (owner, group, others) to access files in the directory, subject to per-file permissions also allowing that.

Comment: Might be worth amending to discuss the meaning of `+x` in directory context. I definitely agree that this answer is correct insofar as it goes -- it's much faster to check the execute bit of an inode than to need to look up the block map and read the first several bytes of a file to see if something has an ELF or script header before being able to decide -- but if the question is read to ask why the *operating system* has such a concept as `+x` at all, as opposed to why a script should have it set, then its use in other contexts is germane.